# Cannot find Ejs module

Tags: ejs

> 

1. Error: Cannot find module 'ejs'
   Require stack:

- C:\projects\node_modules\express\lib\view.js
- C:\projects\node_modules\express\lib\application.js
- C:\projects\node_modules\express\lib\express.js

Comment: Can you provide the minimal code that leads to this error and minimal package information?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instructions

1. npm install ejs
2. app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
3. npm i express